# Why does embedded style render different than linked CSS file with same styles?

Tags: css, html, html-rendering

I copied the style section of my HTML into an external CSS file and added a link to the new file.  However the results were slightly different.  Certain tags seem to now be ignored, and others work fine.

Chrome shows differences in the inheritance, but I cannot figure out why.
Here is a link to the offending html and CSS:  http://jsfiddle.net/n36xot86/

```
<body>
    <!-- Header Section -->
    <div class="form-style-1">
        <h1>The School Board of Sarasota County, Florida<span>Construction Services Department.</span></h1>

        <h2> Building Permit Application</h2>
        <!-- Permit Application Section -->
    </div>
</body>
```

From CSS File:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .form-style-1 {
            margin: 10px auto;
            max-width: 800px;
            padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
            font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        }

            .form-style-1 h1 {
                background: #2A88AD;
                padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;
                margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
                font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
                box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
                border: 1px solid #257C9E;
            }

                .form-style-1 h1 > span {
                    display: block;
                    margin-top: 2px;
                    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
</style>
```

When I look at the pages in chrome, I can see that some tags see the ".format-style-1" style and others do not.  Notice that the corners are not rounded.  Here is screen shots: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g0mf.jpg

Comment: You haven't provided enough code context to even guess what is going on. Sadly the images only show a very small portion of the greater contaxt of the code and there could be many reasons for things being different. I suggest place the `<h2>` HTML and the relevent CSS into a https://jsbin.com or https://jsfiddle.net and recreate the situation. Then others can easily diagnose and offer solutions.

Comment: This was meant to be a  generic question.  Is there any reason that a HTML File that references an external CSS file should render differently than the exact same HTML with the EXACT same styles embedded?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We initially coded the styles embedded in the HTML and then later copied all of the styles from the HTML into a external CSS File.  Unfortunately, when we cut the styles from the HTML, we included the HTML Tags:   "style type="text/css"" and "/style" around the styles.

The result were confusing.  Some of the style values worked, and others did not.   Instead of just showing the page unformated it rendered some of the styles which led us to believe that the CSS file was working.

Once we removed the HTML tags from the CSS, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Again, there is some interation happening and without the code no one will be able to diagnose. In a general stance there is no _magic_ that I know of that would cause that.

Comment: I am long time stalker of stack overflow, and am just learning how to contribute.  I am also new to HTML/CSS and find it frustrating that little things like this can trip me up for what seems like hours!